# SQL Join Condition

Tags: sql, join

Suppose we have two tables-Customer & Transaction

```
Customer                       Transaction T
-----------                      ----------------
Cust_Id                          Cust ID
Cust name                        Items 
Cust Address                     Date    
Flag
```

If I join these tables, -

```
select * from Customer C
inner join Transaction T
on C.Cust_id=T.Cust_id
Where C.Flag= 'Y'
```

OR

```
select * from Customer C
inner join Transaction T
on C.Cust_id=T.Cust_id
AND C.Flag='Y'
```

Please anyone can let me know the functional difference b/w the two queries (Please refer the last line of both queries)

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @Kuzgun It took me a bit to notice the difference as well, but `WHERE` changed to `AND` for the `JOIN` clause.

Comment: @ChrisHayes, what would be the difference in the output?

Comment: @user3030329 If I knew, I would have put it in an answer. I'm just clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

In case of inner join,There is no difference. Both work in the same way. Query optimizer finally treats them as same.

Below link will help you understand it better

[Link Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/15/sql-server-interesting-observation-of-on-clause-on-left-join-how-on-clause-effects-resultset-in-left-join/)

Comment: Thanks buddy for the reply, but I have experienced difference b/w the two but I am not able to figure it out , what exactly is the difference.

Comment: @user3030329 "I have experienced difference" is not helpful at all. What difference did you notice between these two?

Comment: If you use left/right outer join involving multiple tables, placement of the condition makes the difference. But for innerjoin, there is no difference in performance or the final result.

Comment: I updated the post with a link. That will help you in understanding the placement of where condition.

Answer (score 0):

both condition are same but i think first query is faster than second

Answer (score 0):

ON clause is also filter like a WHERE clause, with difference that ON filter cannot exist without JOIN clause.

In case of INNER JOIN clause, they are treated as same, but in case of LEFT or RIGHT join, ON filter plays a great role.

In fact, you cannot filter result of LEFT(RIGHT) JOIN by column which not exist in other table, and standard practice is to put those columns i ON filter.

Comment: You *can* filter by the column in the left or right joined table. You may get unexpected results unless you check for `C.FLAG IS NULL OR C.FLAG = 'Y'`